# How to load a shared library without loading its dependencies?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, elf

Say I have a library `libfoo.so.1`, which depends (according to `ldd`) on `libbar.so.1`. However, `libbar.so.1` is not available at the moment. My app needs to call a function in `libfoo.so.1` which doesn't require `libbar.so.1` at all.

Is there a way to load `libfoo.so.1`, resolve the function symbol and then call it without having `libbar.so.1` to satisfy the dependency? It's a case of "I know what I'm doing, just let me do it already". I tried the RTLD_LAZY flag, but it still tries to load the `libbar.so.1` library before *not* loading the symbols.

---

*EDIT*

Here's the exact situation.

We have 3 players:

- **`libbar.so.1`**, a shared library located in a path not in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `ldconfig`, and whose dependencies are all resolved
- **`libfoo.so.1`**, a shared library located in a different directory than `libbar`, but which depends on `libbar`. At runtime, `libfoo` will know where to locate `libbar`.
- **`App`**, a binary application which needs to load `libfoo` at some point during runtime.

`App` doesn't know where to find `libbar`, but knows that `libfoo` knows. What I'm trying to accomplish is having an init function in `libfoo` which would simply change `App`'s current working directory to where `libbar` is located to finally resolve all the dependencies and make everyone happy.

`libfoo` will *eventually* need to call stuff in `libbar`, just not in this init function. I don't think creating a stub would work since the symbols would eventually need to resolve to the *real* functions.

Comment: Good that you mentioned RTLD_LAZY - it shows you've tried and stops me going off on the red herring path of suggesting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, variables are still resolved even with `RTLD_LAZY`, so in general you do need all the libraries to be linked. Seems like you should create a stub `libbar.so.1` that has no functionality and can be found by the linker.

Comment: I think this would work, but you need the stub to define all the symbols that libfoo.so depends on. The definitions themselves can be stubs though.

Comment: As tommieb75 points out, the stubs don't actually have to be in libbar.so, but their symbols must be defined somewhere.

Comment: I don't think you need to define all the symbols, isn't that what `RTLD_LAZY` will do?

Comment: `RTLD_LAZY` is merely advisory. It's possible that due to things potentially outside your control, it will be ignored (for instance, a system that doesn't support lazy binding, the program having been started suid, or administrator configuration to disable lazy binding for security or robustness purposes).

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, have you thought of interpositioning dependency - simply create a identical function with the same signature, parameters etc and let the linker resolve this function and ignore libbar.so.1? Since you did not mention this, I thought I'd suggest this.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: I don't think this would work. Each library has a list of dependencies encoded into it at link time that is independent of the set of undefined symbols. The loader will try to find those dependencies whether or not they are actually needed.

Comment: @Jay: The loader's path is embedded into the executable in order for the dynamic loading of the function...I was thinking of in terms of preventing the dynamic load by specifying a duplicate function with same signature thus forcing the linker to use that version instead...

Comment: @Jay: Just saw your response to Adam's answer, that was my line of thinking...a stub for want of a better word...

Comment: @tommieb75, that would be fine. It doesn't matter where the symbols are defined as long as they're defined somewhere. libbar.so still has to exist though, even if it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

Another thought:  Would extracting (use ar(1)) the necessary function(s) from `libfoo.so.1`, either into a `.o` or into another `.so` file, and then linking against that extract help?  I'm assuming the reference to `libbar.so.1` is in a libfoo function that is not called (even indirectly) from your program.

Comment: Actually, dynamic libraries aren't `ar`chives.

Answer (score 0):

What's the actual requirement here?  Merely linking a library doesn't do much, and is usually benign.  Do you lack the library?  Just create a stub library of the same name.  You want to control or preempt the use of symbols in the library?  Put them in another library (with the right version tags!) and LD_PRELOAD it.

I guess the meta-question here is that I don't see what value being able to preempt the dependency linkage has.  It's just a helper function.

Answer (score -1):

Use dlopen to load the library and dlsym to get the function you need.

Comment: That's how he tried the RTLD_LAZY flag; you don't get to specify that when the library is linked in at startup.